# Getting SQLCODE and SQLSTATE from select query inside Procedure DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, db2, execute

I have a procedure and all I want is the SQLSTATE and SQLCODE from a select query. I am NOT interested in the result itself.

```
 Create procedure select_test(IN query varchar(1024))
 Language sql
 BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE V_QUERY VARCHAR(24576);
DECLARE V_ERRORMSG VARCHAR(2048) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE V_SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE V_SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE STMT STATEMENT;
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR STMT;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING,NOT FOUND
BEGIN
GET DIAGNOSTICS
EXCEPTION
1 V_ERRORMSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;
VALUES(SQLSTATE,SQLCODE)INTO V_SQLSTATE, V_SQLCODE;
END;

SET V_QUERY = QUERY;
PREPARE STMT FROM V_QUERY;

OPEN C1; CLOSE C1;

 End@
```

All I need is the SQLCODE,SQLSTATE and MESSAGE_TEXT. The result of the select is not important. 
Query is something like

```
 SELECT A,B,C from TAB_A;
```

with a wrong table in the query.

Thanks to @Mark Barinstein I got hinted to the cursor part so thank you for that lready.

The problem is that I get SQLCODE -504 and it should be -204. So it is not the SQLCODE of the select.

I am running DB2 Windows v10.5

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about DB2, but it looks like Standard SQL SPL. Instead of `VALUES(SQLSTATE,SQLCODE)INTO V_SQLSTATE, V_SQLCODE;` try adding it to GET DIAGNOSTICS: `V_ERRORMSG = MESSAGE_TEXT, V_SQLSTATE = SQLSTATE, V_SQLCODE = SQLCODE;`

Comment: Additionally: If you don't care about the result of the Select, you don't have to open/close the cursro, prepare will already fail when the table doesn't exist...

Comment: the adding doesn't work in DB2

Comment: deleting the open and close worked

Comment: You use a `continue` handler, there's another error when you open the cursor which overrides the 1st error.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Now I got it to work.

Comment: Don't make these procedures to broad because you'll open your system to injection.

Comment: I know but it is a local system.